# (Flash-AS3)Why Main class doesn't see instance names which are directly written on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In Flash Professional CS6, one of my projects' main class doesn't see instance names directly written on object's property window, I haven't seen this problem before, it has to see my instance names. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Can't really provide much help without more information. Have you double checked for typos?

Comment: Yes I did.
There is a Box movieclip, I created one instance of that on the stage and named it Box1 , when I try to use it on main class like "Box1.x=0" or something like that, it doesn't see it. When I try , trace(Box1); it returns null.

Comment: Is it on a guide layer ? or are you trying to reference it on a frame where it doesn't exist ?

Comment: no it's on a fream that it does exist on, first I use gotoAndStop(5) and Box1 exists on frame5.

Comment: If your main class is document class then it can get instance names from stage.

Answer (score 1):

Your `gotoAndStop()` statement does not immediately force Flash to change frames, so if these two statements of yours are coming one right after another, they are both executed in context of your previous frame, where `Box1` is still null. You should use some primitive variables (int, String, maybe up to Array of something) to support data integrity when you travel between frames. These are to be initialized somewhere (in case of Array) and used throughout your timeline code.

Comment: +1   
Fire an event or do a callback at the end of frame 5 then check the box. This way you can be sure that box is made

Answer (score 0):

Returning (null) means it is not there, Some code how you have implemented it would be nice..
Here is an easy way to ensure your variables are global in flash,

Creat new flash file, create an empty movieClip "container" and make your whole project inside that MovieClip treating it as the main time line, put all you action script on the main stage timeline so when you reference something:

```
     container.myObject.x = 50 
     container.gotoAndStop(5);
```

By doing this way everything is always available, I think its good practice as you NEVER  need to worry about missing items, or variables. Also it makes it easier to move your project from project to project as all the content is inside the MovieClip(container) its a lot easier then re-copying frames on the main timeline..